# Texture not visible

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

The texture is not rendered on the wall I made, it only appears as a color. How can I fix this?

Project link:https://dosya.co/wdidmqqdq2js/sahilduv.blend.html

[image]

Comment: it looks like all your modifiers mess up the object and thus the projection of the image, can't you apply them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your *Remesh* modifier completely messes up the UV probably because it virtually changes the mesh. I guess you need to apply or remove it:

[image]

Or use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* to avoid UVs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that remesh modifier even necessary in the first place?

Comment: @ L0Lock, I don't know, you can't always guess why the user has used one thing or another  :/

Answer (score 2):

You got no coordinates for the Texture!
You should either uv unwrap All the objects or use this setup!
[image]

Comment: I would recommend UV unwrap if your exporting outside the blender!

Answer (score 0):

You need to UV unwrap the wall. Select it, go to Edit Mode, press U, and choose Smart UV Project. You'll be able to see the texture now, and you can tweak the UV mapping as needed

Comment: There is no such thing as "auto project" in vanilla Blender.

Comment: yeah you're right I meant Smart UV Project